# Find if any styles from an array exists in the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this code to test if a style exists in the document.

```
Sub StyleExists()
MsgBox Style("Test")
End Sub

Function Style(strStyle) As Boolean
   Dim t
   On Error Resume Next
   Style = True
   Set t = ActiveDocument.Styles(strStyle)
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then Style = False
   Err.Clear
End Function
```

Instead of checking for one style I want to do it for multiple styles. My idea is to store a list of styles in an array and check if any of them exist.

How can I extend the code?

Comment: Well, actually what I want is to check if any of the styles used in a document does not exist in an array. So, if the document has a style not listed in an array, it should return false

Comment: Put your forbidden style names in a scripting.dictionary. e.g. ForbiddenNames then you can do If ForbiddenNames.Exists(<stylenamestring>) which will return false if the Document style is not in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution. We get all the styles in the document and check to see they are actually being used, because `Document.Styles` just lists all styles available in the current document. Using another function, `IsInArray`, we check whether each used style is in the array you passed into the function. If any of them is not, then our function returns false.

```vb
Sub StyleExists()
Dim arr() as Variant
arr = Array("Style1", "Style2") 'Populate array with names of your styles
MsgBox AllStylesInArray(arr) 'changed function name to make it more sensible
End Sub

Function AllStylesInArray(arr() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim doc As Document, s As Style

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    AllStylesInArray = True

    For Each s in doc.Styles
        If s.InUse = True Then 
            With doc.Content.Find 
                .ClearFormatting 
                .Text = "" 
                .Style = s 
                .Execute Format:=True 
                If .Found = True Then 
                    AllStylesInArray = IsInArray(s.NameLocal, arr)
                    If AllStylesInArray = False Then Exit For
                End If 
            End With 
        End If 
    Next s
End Function

Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
'DESCRIPTION: Function to check if a value is in an array of values
'INPUT: Pass the function a value to search for and an array of values of any data type.
'OUTPUT: True if is in array, false otherwise
Dim element As Variant
On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
    For Each element In arr
        If element = valToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
Exit Function
IsInArrayError:
On Error GoTo 0
IsInArray = False
End Function
```

For more understanding of some of these functions see: [`Style.InUse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.style.inuse) and [How to check if value is in array](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/check-if-value-is-in-array-vba/)

Answer (score 1):

An array is a poor solution.  VBA offers a much more useable object, the scripting dictionary, available from the Microsoft Scripting RUntime library.  The following code shows how to populate a suitable scripting dictionary and then how to check if a style name is in the list of forbidden names.

```
Option Explicit

Public ForbiddenStyleName                       As Scripting.Dictionary


Public Sub PopulateForbiddenStyleNameDict()

    Set ForbiddenStyleName = New Scripting.Dictionary
    ' use one .add per stylename
    With ForbiddenStyleName

        ' Scripting dictionaries require an Key and a value for each .Add
        ' In this case we just duplicate the key as a value.
        .Add Key:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).NameLocal, Item:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).NameLocal
        .Add ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal, ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).NameLocal
        .Add "UserStyle2", "UserStyle2"
        .Add "UserStyle4", "UserStyle4"
        ' ...etc
    End With

End Sub


Public Sub DemonstrationOfForbiddenStyleExists()

    PopulateForbiddenStyleNameDict

    ' Pass the style name as a string
    If ForbiddenStyleName.Exists("UserStyle2") Then

        MsgBox "UserStyle2 is used in the document"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying this method but it gives **Compile Error: User-defined type not defined** on line 2 , i.e. **Public ForbiddenStyleName                       As Scripting.Dictionary**

Comment: You need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  In the VBA IDE go Tools.References. Then scroll down until you find the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  Click in the Checkbox next to the name and then click OK.  The code should now compile and run OK.